# How would you express this using mathematical symbols?

Tags: prime-factorization

"The largest common denominator of a and b is also a denominator of c."

"The largest common denominator of a and b is equal to the largest common denominator of a and c".

Comment: With "denominator of $c$" do you mean : "it divides $c$" ?

Comment: If so : $\forall x \ (x=\text {gcd}(a,b) \to x|c)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Why introduce an $x$ and not simply write $\gcd(a,b)\mid c$?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA. Yes exactly, that's what I mean. Can you please write a reply with a detailed explanation of the notation and symbols used in your reply? I would also like to point out that I meant this to be expressed as two separate statements.

Comment: Does "largest common denominator"  mean GCD = greatest common divisor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**$1)$ $\gcd(a,b)|c$**

$\gcd(a,b)$ means largest common denominator between $a$ and $b$;

$x|y$ means $x$ divide $y$;

**$2)$ $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,c)$**

Comment: I see. Thank you. I was surprised to see that there is not a more elegant way to express this. Perhaps it's use is rare and so nobody care to find a more elegant way of expressing it?

Comment: In my opinion that is a elegant way to express it!

Comment: I will consider it. It depends on my mood.

Comment: @user504882: What do you find lacking here? It is short, clear and straightforward in the extreme. Are you sure you're not confusing "elegant" with "obscure"?

Comment: @Henning Makholm I agree the answer is very short and intelligible. It is not at Arnaldo I direct my complaint, but at the mathematical language itself. I think the computational method for finding if $a$ divides $b$, and for finding the largest denominator of $a$ and $b$ is basically the same, and the symbols should reflect that.